# Passing to overloaded function - java

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I am writing a small program that calculates tax based on the type of employee and the amount of hours worked (overtime vs non overtime). I will include a complete copy of my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Payroll
{   
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        private int empType;
        private double contractorId;
        private double empPayRate;
        private double empHours;
        private double empOtHours;
        private double empOtPay;
        private double fedTax;
        private double stateTax;
        private double empGrossPay;
        private double empNetPay;
        private double empFedTax;
        private double empStateTax;
        private double empTotalTax;
        private double empRegPay;

    public int empTypeCalc()
    //calculate employee type

    {
        System.out.printf("What type of employee is this?%nEnter 1 for regular employee and 2 for contractors, or 3 to quit: ");
        int empType = input.nextInt();

            if (empType == 1)
            {
            System.out.printf("Input employee's pay rate:%n");
            empPayRate = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("Input employee's hours worked:%n");
            empHours = input.nextDouble();

            grossPayCalc(empPayRate, empHours);
            }

            else if (empType == 2)
            {
            System.out.printf("Input contractor's pay rate:%n");
            empPayRate = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("Input contractors's hours worked:%n");
            empHours = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("Input contractors's ID number:%n");
            contractorId = input.nextInt();

            grossPayCalc(empPayRate, empHours, contractorId);
            }

            else if (empType == 3)
            {
            System.out.printf("Ending program. Have a nice day.%n");
            }

            else
            {
            System.out.printf("Invalid employee type entered please retry.%n");
            empTypeCalc();
            }
            return empType;
    }

    public double grossPayCalc(double empPayRate, double empHours)
    //calculate regular employee pay

    {
        if (empHours <= 40)
        {
            empGrossPay = empPayRate * empHours;

            taxCalc(empHours, empPayRate, empGrossPay);
        }
        else
        {
            otPayCalc(empHours, empPayRate, empGrossPay);
        }
        return empPayRate;
    }


    public double otPayCalc(double empHours, double empPayRate, double empGrossPay)
    //calculate Overtime pay for regular employees

    {   
        if (empHours <= 65)
        {
            empOtHours = empHours - 40;
            empRegPay = 40 * empPayRate;
            empOtPay = empOtHours * empPayRate * 1.5;
            empGrossPay = empOtPay + empRegPay;

            otTaxCalc(empOtPay, empOtHours, empRegPay, empGrossPay, empHours, empPayRate);
        }
        else if (empHours > 65)
        {
            System.out.println("Employee May not work more than 65 Hours.%n");
            empTypeCalc();
        }
        return empOtHours;
    }

    public double grossPayCalc(double empPayRate, double empHours, double contractorId)
    //calculate contractor pay

    {
        if (empHours <= 50)
        {
            empGrossPay = empPayRate * empHours;
            System.out.printf("Contractor's gross pay is $%.2f.%n%n", empGrossPay);
            empTypeCalc();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf("Contractor may not work more than 50 hours per week. Please try again.%n%n");
            empTypeCalc();
        }
        return empPayRate;
    }

    public double otTaxCalc(double empOtPay, double mpOtHours, double empRegPay, double empGrossPay, double empHours, double empPayRate)
    //calc tax for regular employees

    {
            System.out.printf("Please enter Federal Tax Rate. (e.g. 7.5 would be 7.5%)%n");
            fedTax = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("Please enter State Tax Rate. (e.g. 7.5 would be 7.5%)%n");
            stateTax = input.nextDouble();

            empFedTax = (empGrossPay / 100) * fedTax;
            empStateTax = (empGrossPay / 100) * stateTax;
            empTotalTax = empStateTax + empFedTax;
            empNetPay = empGrossPay - empTotalTax;

            System.out.printf("Employee's Federal tax ammount is $%.2f.%n", empFedTax);
            System.out.printf("Employee's State tax ammount is $%.2f.%n", empStateTax);
            System.out.printf("Employee's total tax ammount is $%.2f.%n", empTotalTax);
            System.out.printf("Employee's Federal Tax ammount is $%.2f.%n", empNetPay);
            empTypeCalc();

            return empFedTax;
    }

    public double taxCalc(double empHours, double empPayRate, double empGrossPay)
    {
            System.out.printf("Please enter Federal Tax Rate. (e.g. 7.5 would be 7.5%)%n");
            fedTax = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("Please enter State Tax Rate. (e.g. 7.5 would be 7.5%)%n");
            stateTax = input.nextDouble();

            empFedTax = (empGrossPay / 100) * fedTax;
            empStateTax = (empGrossPay / 100) * stateTax;
            empTotalTax = empStateTax + empFedTax;
            empNetPay = empGrossPay - empTotalTax;

            System.out.printf("Employee's Federal tax ammount is $%.2f.%n", empFedTax);
            System.out.printf("Employee's State tax ammount is $%.2f.%n", empStateTax);
            System.out.printf("Employee's total tax ammount is $%.2f.%n", empTotalTax);
            System.out.printf("Employee's Federal Tax ammount is $%.2f.%n", empNetPay);
            empTypeCalc();

            return empFedTax;
    }
}
```

My first function has you input what type of employee is it (contractor or regular) then asks some basic information (empPayRate and empHours) the part that passes to my grossPayCalc for the regular employees seems to have an error. This is the code that passes the to grossPayCalc.

```
    if (empType == 1)
    {
    System.out.printf("Input employee's pay rate:%n");
    empPayRate = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.printf("Input employee's hours worked:%n");
    empHours = input.nextDouble();

    grossPayCalc(empPayRate, empHours);
    }
```

this should pass to

```
public double grossPayCalc(double empPayRate, double empHours)
//calculate regular employee pay

{
    if (empHours <= 40)
    {
        empGrossPay = empPayRate * empHours;

        taxCalc(empHours, empPayRate, empGrossPay);
    }
    else
    {
        otPayCalc(empHours, empPayRate, empGrossPay);
    }
    return empPayRate;
}
```

After that I get the error.

```
What type of employee is this?
Enter 1 for regular employee and 2 for contractors, or 3 to quit: 1
Input employee's pay rate:
50
Input employee's hours worked:
40
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversio
n = ')'
        at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
        at Payroll.taxCalc(Payroll.java:146)
        at Payroll.grossPayCalc(Payroll.java:72)
        at Payroll.empTypeCalc(Payroll.java:36)
        at PayrollTest.main(PayrollTest.java:6)
```

I am not sure what causes this error. Is this an error with passing the method/from method overloading? I would love to know what causes this error, and how I could prevent it from ever happening in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is caused by `System.out.printf("Please enter Federal Tax Rate. (e.g. 7.5 would be 7.5%)%n");` within the method `taxCalc`.

You probably want to print `7.5%` but the percentage sign is interpreted as a format specifier.

Try `...would be 7.5%%)...`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this method `taxCalc`.

Try to add a `%` sign to escape the `%` sign.

So, just replace this line:

```
System.out.printf("Please enter Federal Tax Rate. (e.g. 7.5 would be 7.5%)%n");
```

with

```
System.out.printf("Please enter Federal Tax Rate. (e.g. 7.5 would be 7.5%%)%n");
```

Then do the same thing for the other similar lines.

Answer (score 0):

In your taxCalc method you have a percent symbol and a bracket after it. You should use double percent sign to make it to work, like this:

`System.out.printf("Please enter Federal Tax Rate. (e.g. 7.5 would be 7.5%%)%n");`